# Can OSX mail auto-search & complete a mail address?

Tags: macos, mail.app, contacts

In Outlook there is this highly useful feature to automatically search and complete a mail address in the recipient field (To:) with `CTRL+K`. Even if you never mailed with someone before, it will search for your input in any global address books you're syncing with (like your company's account). When there is only one match, it auto-prefills it, so it saves the hassle of looking someone up, copying their address and only after that pasting it in your mail window

Can OSX mail automatically search and complete a mail address you've never mailed with before, but which is in one of the address books you're syncing with?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Mail App could auto-fill the email address according to your Contacts even though you've mailed with before. Certainly, you can search the whole Contacts by your self.

Comment: Thanks, this was already clear. But people in a global address book (for example your colleagues) are not in your Contacts. So my question is how can I make it auto-complete from there? Outlook has the shortcut `ctrl+K` for that, was wondering if OSX Mail had the same.

Comment: Yes, know, input a part of it and click <kbd>^</kbd> + K, outlook will auto-completet it if have conflict outlook will bring you a list. let me check if Apple Mail can handle the global address books

Comment: your global address books is on Exchange Server, right?

Comment: Hi, @JordannGross. I haven't got a test environment of Exchange server. So, I 'm not provide you an answer, sorry. But let me guess, you can goto "System Preferences"->"internet Accounts" and add an exchange account, the account will be sync to the Contact automatically, so you can use these as if the iCloud account. and I guess these contacts are easy be deleted. You can backup your whole Contact first and try